# How to block UDP traffic from specific countries in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm from India and I run game server on UDP port 27015. I'm using EC2 service. From past few months, we are facing DDoS attacks from outside India on my UDP port.

I tried enabling security groups to block Ips but it fails.

Is there any way to block non Indian UDP  traffic on Amazon EC2  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Amazon CloudFront and AWS WAF both offer geo blocking. However, I don't think they will work with UDP traffic.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Yes exactly. They work for TCP protocol. But I have seen one guy achieved it. This is the his server IP address. 13.248.132.227:11011. IP: 13.248.132.227 PORT: 11011 and it is accepting only Indian traffic on UDP port.

Comment: you can use WAF.

Comment: @Adiii : How ? Can you please clear it  ? I'm really tired to daily DDoS.

Comment: @Adiii Because what I've seen in WAF is that, firstly it doesn't directly work with EC-2 and secondly it doesn't support UDP. I might be wrong.

Comment: yes, you right about UDP, my mistake. so you can use nginx at you instance level

Comment: @Adiii : But DDoS attack on my UDP is like 60-70 gbps. Will nginx able to handle it ?

Comment: depend on your instance. If it able to Handel such huge DDos so Nginx will also able to handle

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late here but you can use Network ACL to block UDP traffic